# Pagination for multiple loops

Tags: loop, pagination

How to merge Loops and make the overall pagination.
Is displayed on the first page (the numbers - this post):
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8 9
On the second page:
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10 11
And it is necessary to be displayed completely new positions on the second page.
Here is the code:

```
<!-- 1 LOOP BEGIN -->
<div class="news_row">
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; $do_not_duplicate = array(); ?>
<?php $news_row_1 = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2&paged=' . $paged); ?>
<?php while ($news_row_1->have_posts()) : $news_row_1->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
<!-- 1 LOOP END -->

<!-- 2 LOOP BEGIN -->
<div class="news_row">
<?php $args1 = array ('posts_per_page'=>2,'paged'=>$paged,'post__not_in'=>$do_not_duplicate); ?>
<?php $news_row_2 = new WP_Query($args1); ?>
<?php while ($news_row_2->have_posts()) : $news_row_2->the_post();?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
<!-- 2 LOOP END -->

<!-- 3 LOOP BEGIN -->
<div class="news_row">
<?php $args2 = array ('posts_per_page'=>2,'paged'=>$paged,'post__not_in'=>$do_not_duplicate); ?>
<?php $news_row_3 = new WP_Query($args2); ?>
<?php while ($news_row_3->have_posts()) : $news_row_3->the_post();?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
<!-- 3 LOOP END -->

<!-- 4 LOOP BEGIN -->
<?php $args4 = array ('posts_per_page'=>3,'paged'=>$paged,'post__not_in'=>$do_not_duplicate); ?>
<?php $news_row_5 = new WP_Query($args4); ?>
<?php while ($news_row_5->have_posts()) : $news_row_5->the_post();?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<!-- 4 LOOP END -->
```